# Is it possible to use otf fonts on winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, opentype

I've tried using Open Type Fonts both for labels, textboxes and when drawing in a paint-event. But it doesn't work. Is there any way to make Open Type Font work?

Comment: Font textFont = new Font("Arial Bold", 18F);
            g.DrawString("12", textFont, solidbrush, 109, 40); why cant you use like this.

Comment: I can, but i only works with True Type Font. I.e. Myriad Pro won't work.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @Frederik - the font rendered on screen is not changed. It is still Microsoft Sans Serif. And when trying to create a label a dialog tells me that only True Type Fonts are supported for labels.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible in Winforms, GDI+ only supports TrueType fonts.  You'll have to move to WPF to get OpenType support.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `System.Windows.Media` namespace as you would do in WPF, here you have an example:

```
public static string GetFontList(String ElementSeparator)
    {
        string r = "";

        // WPF incl Adobe and OpenType
        foreach (System.Windows.Media.FontFamily fontFam in System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
        {
            r += fontFam.Source;
            r += ElementSeparator;
        }

        // True type, incl Type face names e.g. Arial Rounded MT Bold
        foreach (System.Drawing.FontFamily f in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
        { 
            if(!r.Contains(f.Name))
            {
            r += f.Name;
            r += ElementSeparator;
            }
        }            

        return r;
    }
```