# Get a list of fonts (including opentype fonts) in C# winform

Tags: winforms, opentype

Is it possible to get a list of fonts (including open type fonts) in c# winforms.

I don't need to use the font, I just need the list.

```
        InstalledFontCollection installedFonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
        var fontList = installedFonts.Families;
```

The above code only supplies True Type fonts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12935039/529282

Comment: Why do you say it "only supplies True Type fonts"? How are you differentiating between TrueType and OpenType?